# Move constructor for std::string from char*

Tags: c++, string, c++11, move-semantics

I have a function `f` returning a `char*`. The function documentation says:

```
The user must delete returned string
```

I want to construct a `std::string` from it. The trivial things to do is:

```
char* cstring = f();
std::string s(cstring);
delete cstring;
```

Is it possibile to do it better using C++ features? I would like to write something like

```
std::string(cstring)
```

avoiding the leak.

Comment: You can put the result of `f()` into  `unique_ptr`, then use that to initialize the string. You still need two lines of code. You should complain to whoever wrote `f()`.

Comment: and abstract away the conversion.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Why two lines of code?  What's wrong with `std::string(std::unique_ptr<char[]>(f()).get())` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ha! Yes of course, that would do nicely (although some might object that there's too much going on.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sure, and in a statement block, breaking into multiple simpler steps makes sense.  But the one-liner is awfully convenient where there is no block, e.g. initializers and single expression lambdas.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why complain? Perhaps `f()` was written in C?

Comment: @j_kubik Unlikely, otherwise calling `delete` on the returned pointer would be an error.

Comment: @juanchopanza Possibly... But is is also possible that documentation said "delete" without meaning `operator delete()` but just generally releasing memory - though I agree that in such case it would probably have said `free` instead.

Comment: @j_kubik All the more reason to complain to the author :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::string` will make a copy of the null terminated string argument and manage that copy. There's no way to have it take ownership of a string you pass to it. So what you're doing is correct, the only improvement I'd suggest is a check for `nullptr`, assuming that is a valid return value for `f()`. This is necessary because the `std::string` constructor taking a `char const *` requires that the argument point to a valid array, and not be `nullptr`.

```
char* cstring = f();
std::string s(cstring ? cstring : "");
delete[] cstring;   // You most likely want delete[] and not delete
```

Now, if you don't need all of `std::string`'s interface, or if avoiding the copy is important, then you can use a `unique_ptr` to manage the string instead.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> s{f()}; // will call delete[] automatically
```

You can get access to the managed `char *` via `s.get()` and the string will be `delete`d when `s` goes out of scope.

Even if you go with the first option, I'd suggest storing the return value of `f()` in a `unique_ptr` before passing it to the `std::string` constructor. That way if the construction throws, the returned string will still be deleted.

Comment: Hm. The `unique_ptr` should be used anyway to avoid a leak if the `std::string`-ctor throws.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way for a `std::string` to take ownership of a buffer you pass.

Nor to take responsibility of cleaning up such a buffer.

In theory, an implementation, knowing all the internal details, *could* add a way for a `std::string` to take over buffers allocated with their allocator, but I don't know of any implementation which does.
Nor is there any guarantee doing so would actually be advantageous, depending on implementation-details.

Answer (score 1):

This code can never be correct:

```
std::string s(cstring);
delete cstring;
```

The `std::string` constructor that takes a character pointer, requires a NUL-terminated string.  So it is *multiple* characters.

`delete cstring` is scalar delete.

Either you are trying to create a string from a character scalar (in which case, why the indirection?)

```
std::string s(cstring[0]);
delete cstring;
```

or you have multiple characters, and should delete accordingly

```
std::string s(cstring);
delete [] cstring;
```

Check the other answers for the recommended way to make sure `delete[]` gets used, e.g.

```
std::string(std::unique_ptr<char[]>(f()).get())
```

Comment: This is why comments should allow code.  This is an important point, but not an answer.

Comment: @MobyDisk: Indeed.  On the other hand, the upvote button says "This is useful" and not "This is a complete answer to every aspect of the question".

Comment: Granted.  Is there a meta discussion on that topic?  I've been downvoted to hell in the past, by people with similar rep to you, for not answering the entire question.

Comment: `unique_ptr` when constructed from `(char*)0`, will return null on `.get()` fine.  `std::string` when constructed from `(char const*)0` will execute undefined behavior I think?  So the construct at the end of your post seems overly dangerous.

Comment: @Yakk: Who said that `f()` can return null?

Comment: @BenVoigt More importantly, who said it **cannot**?  Good code is generous in what it accepts and strict in what it produces.

Comment: @Yakk: Well, the line in the question `std::string s(cstring);` says that it cannot

Comment: @BenVoigt Then the next line says it is a single-character pointer, so I wouldn't put THAT much trust in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string steal_char_buffer( std::unique_ptr<char[]> buff ) {
  std::string s = buff?buff.get():""; // handle null pointers
  return s;
}
std::string steal_char_buffer( const char* str ) {
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buff(str); // manage lifetime
  return steal_char_buffer(std::move(buff));
}
```

now you can type

```
std::string s = steal_char_buffer(f());
```

and you get a `std::string` out of `f()`.

You *may* want to make the argument of `steal_char_buffer` be a `const char*&&`.  It is mostly pointless, but it might lead to some useful errors.

If you can change the interface of `f`, make it return a `std::string` directly or a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Another good idea is to wrap `f` in another function that returns a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` or `std::string`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> good_f() {
  return std::unique_ptr<char[]>(f());
}
```

and/or

```
std::string good_f2() {
  auto s = good_f();
  return steal_char_buffer( std::move(s) );
}
```

Comment: Won't that make a copy of the buffer then delete the original?  I don't think that is what the question is about.  He wants to specifically avoid the copy and delete.

Comment: @MobyDisk I figured the OP wanted to avoid the ugly syntax of having to remember the delete (extra lines of noise)